# Lead status not available for editing

Tags: picklist, leads

I created the following picklist values for a lead status on a lead & referral object(New , Nuturing , Close converted , closed not converted)

However the **new** status picklist is not showing on person referal record type and when i narrow down to the Person Referral record type, the lead status is not even available for editing and New does not show in the front end either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have created the lead status picklist field for the lead & referral object, but have not made it available for the person referral record type. To resolve this, you need to add the lead status field to the page layout for the person referral record type and make sure it's visible.

Then you can select the new picklist value from the list of available options. If you are still unable to see the new status picklist value, it might be necessary to check your field level security settings to ensure that the field is accessible for the desired profile.