# Lead Status Picklist Not Available For Editing

Tags: record-type, leads, dependent-picklist, status, path

I'd like the Lead Status picklist to contain different values depending on Record Type, but the Lead Status field isn't available for editing as I would expect with other dependent picklists. Lead Status is available and on the page layout for both Record Types, as suggested [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/395221/lead-status-not-available-for-editing). The end goal is for both record types to have a unique Path. I've seen some answers suggesting that I use Support Processes, but I'm not sure how this could be done.

EDIT: Resolved by using Lead Processes

Comment: you need to use `Lead Processes`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Surprised that I couldn't find that anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of Lead Statuses by record type is done by:

- Setting up [Lead Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_processes.htm&type=5) (typically, one per record type). Note these are deployed as metadata type `BusinessProcess`
- Assign your Lead recordtype(s) to a business process by editing the record type
- Then you edit the [Lead Statuses by Lead business process](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm&type=5)

This technique is also used for Opportunities (StageName), Cases (Status), and Solutions (Status).